# Transfer JSON data to Heroku Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, heroku

**I am quite new to Rails and noticed that none of my data from my local environment was being pushed to the Heroku environment using the `heroku run rake db:migrate` command.**
**In particular I was wondering how to transfer the `JSON` data to the Heroku environment.**

**Gem File:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'figaro'
gem 'angular-rails'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-script', '~> 2.2.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

end
```

**/config/environments/production.rb:**

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true


  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true


  config.serve_static_files = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = true


  config.assets.digest = true


  config.log_level = :debug


  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
end
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
myApp.controller("BlogController", function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('/assets/blogs.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.blogs = data;

    String.prototype.trunc = String.prototype.trunc ||
      function(n){
      // this will return a substring and
      // if its larger than 'n' then truncate and append '...' to the string and return it.
      // if its less than 'n' then return the 'string'
      return this.length>n ? this.substr(0,n-1)+'...' : this;
    };

  });
});
```

**I am also receiving the following error in my console for the deployed environment: `Error: Unknown provider: eProvider <- e`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changing the pattern of the AngularJs controller resolved the issue:**

```
myApp.controller("BlogController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('/assets/blogs.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.blogs = data;

    String.prototype.trunc = String.prototype.trunc ||
      function(n){
      // this will return a substring and
      // if its larger than 'n' then truncate and append '...' to the string and return it.
      // if its less than 'n' then return the 'string'
      return this.length>n ? this.substr(0,n-1)+'...' : this;
    };

  });
}]);
```